# Codeigniter - jquery.min.js:4 Mixed Content: the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter-3

I have a JS script that post data via AJAX. When I put the script on my server, the posting URL is https but when I view the js via view page source online, the URL starts with http.

I am receiving the below error.

jquery.min.js:4 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.mywebsite.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.mywebsite.com/bookmark'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

**Script on server**

```js
$(document).on("click","#bookmark",function(a){a.preventDefault();var t=$(this).attr("bookmark_id"),e=$("input[name=msmm_tn").val(),s=$(this);$.ajax({type:"POST",url:"https://www.mywebsite.com/bookmark",data:{msmm_tn:e,bookmarkid:t},dataType:"json",success:function(a){"X"==a.status&&(s.find("i").addClass("green"),s.removeAttr("href"))}})})
```

When I click the js file in my web browser, the https:// is http. I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Maybe it's cache issue. Clear the browser cache and try again.

Comment: I cleared the cache and all sessions from DB but the .js file still has http as the URL even though I save the file to my server with https. On the server side I can see https in the file, on client side it is http.

Comment: Put `url:"//www.mywebsite.com/bookmark"` and let apache decide to load (probably) secure version.

Comment: I actually just put the second parameter as the URL url:"bookmark" and still http is determined. This seems to only be an issue in Chrome. It works in Firefox just fine. I know that should not matter. weird.

Comment: Please try one more time in new private window of Chrome because that way you will be sure there is no sessions, cookies etc.

Comment: OK, seems like it was indeed a cache issue. Problem resolved. Thanks all.

Comment: Always develop and/or test in private browsing window.

Answer (score 1):

This error is shown when either website is loaded on "HTTPS:"
and your libraries are loaded on "HTTP:"
OR
This error is shown when either website is loaded on "HTTP:"
and your libraries are loaded on "HTTPS:"

In Codeigniter resolve this by editing "config.php".
Open "application/config/config.php" in your project and change the value of

```
$config['base_url']
```

Add "s" in the value
from

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```